# SQLGetDiagField returns SQL_SUCCESS but result in DiagInfoPtr is -1

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I'm using ODBC with MS SQL. When executing query with SQLExecute(hSTMT) I try to receive total row count with

```
   SQLGetDiagField(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hSTMT, 0, SQL_DIAG_CURSOR_ROW_COUNT, &RowCount, SQL_IS_INTEGER, &StrLen);
```

And I receive value -1 in RowCount when executing query like

```
SELECT Username, Password 
FROM dbUser with(nolock) 
WHERE Username LIKE ? 
ORDER BY UserName ASC
```

Though result after SQLExecute is absolutely valid.

When I do ORDER BY FullName,I receive valid row count.

Moreover when I run locally I also receive valid row count, but on production server I receive -1. I've read it could be an issue with performance, but I have the same result even if the query only one that running.

By trying different variants of the query I found out that the problem appears only when I use field names like 'User%'(UserName, UserId, etc.) as first parameter in order by clause. Works fine with ORDER BY FullName, UserName.

What could be the reason for such behaviour? Why the problem appears only in User% like names?

Could it be the issue with ODBC driver?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a compilable minimal sample reproducing the problem?

Comment: @erg Sorry. Production code. And it won't help. Because it works fine in almost all cases. Plus works fine on local environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's appeared that the problem was due to indexes. When I removed indexes for corresponding columns - everything started to work fine. Though everything is pretty slow without indexes so it is a poor decision.

P.S. Indexes preventing usage of TempDB that is used by SQLGetDiagField to obtain row count.

Answer (score 0):

By msdn there may be no exact row count in this header field. See SQLGetInfo, SQL_CA2_CRC_EXACT, ...APPROXIMATE.
SQLFetch may be required to count rows.

Comment: SQLFetch is used for receiving rows required for the page. But I need total row count for quantity of pages. Though such method works fine for other queries and even for the same query, but another order by...